# javascript drowdown list

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down list on my form.

What is the event I would use in javascript that triggers once the user has made a selection on a drop down. I tried on change but that did on work.

```
    DROP DOWN
```

Comment: please provide a piece of code you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange) is the correct event.

**HTML**

```
<select onchange="SelectChanged(this)">
...
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function SelectChanged(obj) {
    ...
}
```

Here's [a very simple working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/RKJpj/) to get you going.